# SQL SERVER XML OUTPUT

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I am trying to combine these 3 sql statements to output into one XML statement that outputs like this example:

```
    <dataset seriesName="Model A12" color="A66EDD" >
            <set value="35" /> 
            <set value="42" /> 
            <set value="31" /> 
            <set value="28" /> 
            <set value="34" /> 
            <set value="30" /> 
    </dataset>

    <dataset seriesName="Model A15" color="F6BD0F">
            <set value="22" /> 
            <set value="25" /> 
            <set value="18" /> 
            <set value="22" /> 
            <set value="17" /> 
            <set value="16" /> 
    </dataset>
```

Here are my SQL Statements:

```
(SELECT CLAIM_NUM as 'CATEGORY_LABEL' from claim_table)
for xml RAW, TYPE,ROOT('CATEGORY');

(SELECT TOTAL_INCURRED_AMT as 'SET_VALUE' from claim_table)
for xml RAW, TYPE, ROOT('DATASET');

SELECT TOTAL_PAID_AMT as 'SET_VALUE' from claim_table
for xml RAW, TYPE, ROOT('DATASET');
```

I have been looking at other examples, but nothing has come close to what I need the output to be.
Thanks is advance for your assistance!

Comment: The output of these statements doesn't match with these results.

Comment: What I posted is what I am trying to achieve.  Right now I have this in 3 separate outputs:
<CATEGORY>
  <row CATEGORY_LABEL="1997-0000055*001" />
</CATEGORY>

<DATASET>
  <row SET_VALUE="233.7300" />
</DATASET>

<DATASET>
  <row SET_VALUE="233.7300" />
</DATASET>